# How to find most common property of object in powershell or Java

Tags: java, arrays, powershell, object, active-directory

So I am a bit stuck on something I am trying to do. I have pulled certain security groups from an Active Directory and created objects for each person in the groups along with who their respective manager is. What I would like to do is find who the most common manager is within a group. Here is an example of something I would have

```
Group           Employee             Manager
Sales           Phil                 Joe
Sales           Chris                Dave
Sales           John                 Dave
Sales           Rebecca              Joe
Sales           Chris                Joe
Sales           Bob                  Annie
HR              Alex                 Steve
HR              Jill                 Steve
HR              Tom                  Maria
HR              Luke                 Steve
Marketing       Don                  Luke
Marketing       Julie                Luke
Marketing       Tim                  Mark
Marketing       Thomas               Luke
```

Basically each object has a Group Name an employee from the group and their manager. I currently have all of these objects in a single array. I just want for each group to find the most common manager. So in this example the Sales group most common manager would be Joe, HR would be Steve, and Marketing would be Luke. The only problem is that there are over 1000 different group names in my actual array so I can't specify to find all groups with  for example 'Sales' as the group name and then find a common manager. I basically need some way to just find all groups that have the same name without specifying it and then out of those find who the most common manager is. If anyone knows a possible way to do this I would really appreciate it. I am struggling figuring out how to do it with object. Any possible leads on how to do this in Java or in powershell will help me out since I have some knowledge of Java as well, although powershell is preferred since that's where I am trying to do this in. If I can't I will probably just go back to the drawing board for another way to try.

Answer (score 1):

in powershell this is  simple: $ArrayOfGroupsUsersAndManagers | group-object Manager <- this will aggregate all groups into groups per exact manager name then you can expand or do weather you want with these groups.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to specifically do this since I don't know the active directory java libraries at all. For a general process though, you would just turn this Array into a map that maps department to a map of managers to count then just iterate over it and get the manager with highest counts for each group. Something like

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(activedirectoryobject ado : adoList) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> groupMap = map.get(adoList.group)
    if(groupMap != null) {
        if(groupMap.contains(adoList.manager) {
            groupMap.put(adoList.manager, groupMap.get(adoList.manager))
        } else {
            groupMap.put(adoList.manager, 1)
        }
    } else {
        Map<String, Integer> newGroup = new HashMap<>();
        newGroup.put(adoList.manager, 1); 
        map.put(adoList.group, newGroup)
    }
}
List<String> managers = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    //entry.getKey() gets the group, entry.getValue()) gets the submap
    int highest = 0;
    String manager = '';
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> subEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(subEntry.getValue() > highest) {
            highest = subEntry.getValue();
            manager = subEntry.getKey();
        }
    }
    managers.add(manager);
}
```

Should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same idea as user3298823, but took a little different approach with the code. You can use Collections.max to get the most common manager and the merge method to increment the count.  Say for example you wanted to look at the Sales group:

```
    Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for ( Record record : records )  {
        if ( !map.containsKey(record.group) ) {
            Map<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
            counts.put(record.manager, 1);
            map.put(record.group, counts);
        } else {
            map.get(record.group).merge(record.manager, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    List<String> mostCommon = new ArrayList<>();

    int max = Collections.max(map.get("Sales").values());

    for ( String manager : map.get("Sales").keySet() ) {
        if ( map.get("Sales").get(manager) == max ) {
            mostCommon.add(manager);
        }
    }
```